# Why is there :nopm: in some photo file names?

Tags: camera, images

I was looking at some of the pictures taken with my camera ([Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en)) and there are some that have `:nopm:` in the file name. The format of the file names are the same, just some contain this after the timestamp, before the extension.

[image]

When I use MTP on windows to copy them to my PC they copy fine, because it removes the <kbd>:</kbd> from the file name.

What is the meaning of the `:nopm:`?

I have added a more detailed picture that shows `:nopm:` does not have anything to do with if it was taken in the morning. This wouldn't make sense anyhow, as the timestamp is already in 24 hour format. 231314 = 11:13PM, there is no need for an AM/PM indicator.

Comment: From what I can tell it is Hangouts that most normally adds the :nopm: to images. Is there a chance you sent/received those ones over Hangouts. To be totally honest it seems like an issue with Google Camera, but I've seen quite a few people point the finger at Hangouts.

Comment: It does look like it originates from Hangouts. From the photos, I remember taking them all while sending them to people over MMS via Hangouts.

Comment: @RossC, if you put that as an answer, I will accept it. It does seem that Hangouts is the cause. I am still not sure what it means, but at least I know what is doing it.

Comment: Per a comment left as an answer by another user: It looks like the `:nopm:` prevents the new Photos app from uploading the image. Perhaps that is its purpose as you mentioned below @Ryan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not related to AM/PM as the screenshot shows. This issue appears to happen due to Google Hangouts. I have heard from a few Moto G owners that this happens a lot on that device, and can cause issues moving to SD card, however, it really seems to be down to Google Hangouts. 
[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/2h6itk/double_photos_from_the_stock_camera_app/) is a mention on Reddit, and on an unrelated thread [the same issue](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/265azy/til_long_pressing_the_send_messageattach_button/) crops up.

Upon reading [this issue](https://github.com/owncloud/android/issues/604) on Github:

> google hangouts produce [sic]images of this form **image_timestamp.:nopm:.png**

There is no easy fix at present, but I will investigate.

Comment: Doesn't really tell us **why** it does this in the first place.

Comment: @KenSharp I haven't forgotten this answer, I just can't get an answer from anyone at the moment. There is nothing in the code I've looked at to explain it, and no answer from Google.

Comment: After thinking about this for some time, I actually think that `:nopm:` means `NO Photo Manager`.  As it appears that the Google+ Photos app will not backup the photos that contain `:nopm:`. This is just a theory.

Comment: @RyanConrad it's actually a good one. It makes sense! Then again, some of these things don't seem to make sense at the best of times! :)